# Is it possible to set up IDLE with 2.7 and 3.2?

Tags: 12.04, idle-python

Is it possible to set up IDLE separately for 2.7 and 3.2 so either version can be used through it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - they work as separate packages in the Ubuntu repositories.

- IDLE for 2.7 can be installed with `sudo apt-get install idle`
- IDLE for 3.2 can be installed with `sudo apt-get install idle3`